# Finder crashes permanently

Tags: finder, crash

I bought an SSD for my Macbook Pro. I did a backup of my hdd disk (as I always do with Time Machine) and used the disk utility to restore that backup to my ssd disk. The restore worked perfectly, but Finder is always crashing and restarting and crashing... So I googled a lot and tried to create a second user account. There the problem does not occur. So it seems to be a account-specific problem. But how can I see where the problem is? I don't want to use the new account, because all settings and preferences are gone.

The crash report:

http://pastebin.com/qQjJedDD

Comment: What if the settings and preferences are causing the crash? You might need to start with moving just your other data to the new account and test. The crash looks quite clean and the thread that went down didn't even get off the ground with good data to establish a stack trace (or the stack/crash data itself is suspect/faulty)

Answer (score 1):

You could just try reinstalling OS X from the recovery partition (see http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763). It fixed a similar issue I had where different applications started crashing on launch. It keeps most user files and settings in place, so it might not fix account-specific issues though.

Or if you don't want to recreate settings, try copying directories like ~/Library/Preferences/ and ~/Library/Containers/ to the new account.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and move the finder preference file found at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` 
out of the
`~/Library/Preferences/` folder and do an immediate relaunch of the finder.

The pref could have a corruption or Possibly ( a guess ) hold a reference that is linked to the old HD that is causing the problem.

You need to do the relaunch quickly or the setting in memory may get written to file before you do.

To relaunch you can hold the 'alt' key and click on the Finder dock item. You should then see the Relaunch Menu item.

[image]

The finder will disappear and the come back in its default settings.

A tip so you know you have a new finder setup is to sort the desktop by for example name. When the finder comes back up the sort should not be on and the folders/files on the desktop will not be ordered but dispersed.

There are other ways to Relaunch the finder but it is best you try that first.

Comment: trashing Finder pref solved a huge probleme I had with finder goobling 17Go of RAM ! wathever I tried. trashed and relaunched finder as markhunt wrote and boom ! back to 24 Mb ... THANK YOU !!! (yes capitals ...)

Answer (score -1):

Same SSD change, same Finder crashes.

I solved my crash by one reboot in Safe mode.